# Why central isogeny of reductive group over general field F map maximal F split torus onto a maximal split F torus

Tags: algebraic-groups

let $f$ be a central isogeny of reductive groups over  a field F, why $f$ map a maximal split $F$ torus onto a maximal split $F$ torus.

Comment: Because it induces an isomorphism of rational-ised character lattices (with Galois action).  This question is not research level, and can be found in the part of any of the standard books dealing with rationality questions.

Comment: @LSpice Thank you for the explanation. I only know how to show it if F is perfect field. The inverse image of a maximal torus defined over F is also maximal torus defined over F. But I don't know how to show it for reductive group over a non perfect field. Could you explain how to proved it in details.

Comment: This is not the place to get detailed proofs of standard results.  One approach (probably not optimal) is to notice that the character lattice of $f^{-1}(T_{F^{\text{alg}}})$ (which is certainly a torus) has the trivial Galois action, so that the $F$-algebra it generates is an $F$-structure for $f^{-1}(T_{F^{\text{alg}}})$.

Comment: @LSpice, I think the pull back (in scheme sense) is not a smooth subgroup scheme over a non perfect field $F$ in general.  The argument works  when F is perfect field.

Comment: Ah, I see.  If you wish to work with pullbacks in the scheme-theoretic sense (not underlying reduced schemes), then the statement is not true.  Let $k = \mathbb F_2((t))$, let $G$ and $G'$ be the group schemes underlying $\ker \mathrm N_{D/k}$ and $D^\times/k^\times$ where $D/k$ is the quaternionic division algebra, and let $f : G \to G'$ be the natural projection.  Then the maximal split torus in $G'$ is trivial, but its pullback to $G$ is the non-smooth scheme $Z(G) = \mu_2$.

Comment: In [your comments](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/328335/why-central-isogeny-of-reductive-group-over-general-field-f-map-maximal-f-split#comment820172_328335), you mentioned pull-backs, but I have been reminded by @anon's [answer](https://mathoverflow.net/a/328620) that your actual question addresses push-forwards.  Accordingly, I'm not sure whether your comment about pull-backs was a separate question, or whether I missed your point.

Answer (score 2):

The image $f(T)$ of a maximal split torus $T$ is a split torus of the same dimension, which is contained in a maximal split torus $T'$. But the maximal split tori have the same dimension, and so $f(T)=T'$ (the maximal split tori are even conjugate, see, for example, Milne 2017, 25.10). [I am assuming that, as the question originally stated, $f$ maps a group to itself. Otherwise, you need to use that the two groups have the same split rank.]

Comment: Just to emphasise, it's split because the isogeny induces a Galois-equivariant isomorphism of ratinalised character lattices.

Comment: @LSpice sorry I didn't write the question clear.  The central isogeny is between two different reductive groups (could be not isomorphism to each other).  So we don't assume the split ranks are same.

Comment: @yshuaiqin, ah, now I see the relevance of pullbacks to your question!  This answer explains why the image of a split torus is split.  As you argue, the pre-image of a torus need not be a torus, but the reduced scheme underlying the pre-image *is* a torus, with the same image, and the rest of the argument goes through.

Answer (score 0):

@LSpice, I figured out how to show the pre-image of a maximal torus defined over $F$ is also defined over $F$( geometrical reduced subscheme of $G_{F}$).  Let $f: G\rightarrow G^{\prime}$ be a central isogeny. By base change to $F_{s}$( separable closure of $F$), all $U_{\alpha}$ ( the unipotent group correspondents to the root $\alpha$) are defined over $F_{s}$. 
$T(F_{s})$ and all $U_{\alpha}(F_s)$ generates $G(F_{s})$ by Bruhat's decomposition. Central isogeny implies $f$ restricted to $U_{\alpha}(F_{s})$ is an isomorphism to $U^{\prime}_{\alpha^{\prime}} (F_{s})$. Therefore, two maximal torus defined over $F_{s}$ of $G^{\prime}$ are conjugate by an element in $f(G(F_{s}))$. This implies the preimage is defined over $F_{s}$. I think we essentially need it is a central isogeny. Do you think it still holds if it is only an isogeny?